# Apollo Mutation Code for Supporting Pub-Sub?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm working on implementing the new Apollo pubsub code using sample code from GitHunt-API and GitHunt-React.  Here is my resolver mutation code *before* working on pubsub. This works:

```
Mutation: {
    createIM: (__, args) => { return connectors.IM.create(args); },
},
```

Also, for reference, here is my current resolver query. This code works:

```
Query: {
    instant_message(_, args) {
        var ret = connectors.IM.findAll({ where: args }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
        return ret;
    }
},
```

Here is my current draft of *implementing pubsub* for this mutation:

```
Mutation: {
    createIM(root, args, context) {
        return Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => (
                connectors.IM.create(args)
            ))
            .then(([args]) =>
                connectors.IM.findAll({ where: args }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues))
            )
            .then(comment => {
                // publish subscription notification
                pubsub.publish('IMAdded', comment);
                return comment;
            });
    },
```

},

In http://localhost:3010/graphiql, this throws an error:

> "Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"

For reference, here's the query code I'm giving graphiql:

**Query:**

```
mutation($fromID: String!, $toID: String!, $msgText: String!){
  createIM(fromID: $fromID, toID: $toID, msgText: $msgText){
    fromID
    toID
    msgText
  }
}
```

**Query Variables:**

```
{
  "fromID": "1",
  "toID": "2",
  "msgText": "Test from GraphIQL"
}
```

What is the error in my Mutation code for pubsub?

Comment: I think it's coming from the following line: `.then(([args]) =>`. It looks like the thing that `create` returns is not actually an array.

Comment: As noted in my post, that code works perfectly in a resolver when referenced in a query: `Query: {
    instant_message(_, args) {
        var ret = connectors.IM.findAll({ where: args }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
        return ret;
    }
},`.  Could the `then(([args]) =>` syntax be interfering?

Comment: Exactly, I think it's a result of that syntax. The error it's printing is what you get when you try to use `[args]` on an object that isn't an array.

Comment: Using breakpoints and console.log, it seems like my `then(([args]) =>` is never getting executed. Does my `connectors.IM.create(args)` need to return a promise? I'm studying lots of web pages about ES6 promises in order to learn how they work.

Comment: ...Just checked. `connectors.IM.create(args)` *does* return a promise. What could explain why my `connectors.IM.findAll` never runs?

Comment: This error is in the code that unpacks the arguments for the `then`. Your promise is returning a value that resolves to the wrong form - it's not an array. Can you add something in between that just does: `.then((x) => console.log(x))`?

Comment: In `.then(([args]) =>`, `args` is coming in as undefined. Per your advice I'm now thinking this may be a matter of finding out how to use Sequelize-returned promises in this kind of pattern. I will open a new StackOverflow ticket to find out more.